# display collection of strings on node.js using express-handlebars on server side

Tags: mysql, node.js, express-handlebars

i have sql query result that i want to display by using express-handlebars

```
var x={} ;
```

//friends table got name|profileName|status attributes

```
 dao.findFriends(req.session.UserName,function(err,rows,fields){
    x=rows;
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        console.log(rows[i].profileName);   
    }
});

res.render('home',{body:'hello ...'+req.session.UserName,friends:x});
```

simple string is displayed fine
but not for the sql result

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
    {{#each friends}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{profileName}}</td>

    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
Had to make the variable **x** accept json array and ..
and push all the result into **x** within for loop

```
var x =[];
dao.findFriends(req.session.UserName,function(err,rows,fields){
            if(!err){
            console.log('listing friends');
            //list in bunch of <li> <ul> </ul>
                for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                    console.log(rows[i].profileName);
                    //x = rows;
                    x.push({
                                    profileName: rows[i].profileName
                                });
                    }
                }
                else
                console.log('err finding people...');
                res.render('home',{body:'hello ...'+req.session.UserName,friends:x});
            });
```

and on html  side refer to fields with **this** prefix

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>

</tr>
{{#each friends}}
<tr>
  <td>{{this.profileName}}</td>

</tr>
{{/each}}
```